# Как в php вывести из массива все данные находящиеся на одном уровне с <code>WMR</code>?

Tags: php, массивы, xml

Вот пример массива XML, и нужно чтобы выводилось именно по wmr, а не по ключу.
Еще я знаю, что можно с помощью коллекций сделать, но не понимаю как сделать

```
<price>
                <code>WMR</code>
                <price>299</price>
                <currency>RUB</currency>
            </price>
            <price>
                <code>WMU</code>
                <price>0</price>
                <currency>UAH</currency>
            </price>
            <price>
                <code>WMX</code>
                <price>0.07</price>
                <currency>mBTC</currency>
            </price>
```

Comment: прайсы циклом перебирай и все что там будет выводиться по ключу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебираете да выводите, в чем проблема то?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($txt);
$result = [];
foreach($xml as $price){
    if($price->code == 'WMR'){
        $result[] = (array)$price;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

можете и xpath использовать

```
$result = $xml->xpath("//price/code[text()='WMR']/..");
```